# Sketch Styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to build some hand drawn styled maps using QGIS.
The styling is working well using some existing styles for inspiration.
I would like to be able to make some of the line-work look more hand drawn with overshoots, gaps and rough alignments.
I think this should be achievable using shape generators to randomise the vertices in polygons but I can't figure a methodology that works. [image: Sketch Style]

Comment: This works to create overshoots extend(segments_to_lines($geometry),10,10)

Comment: @BERA thanks for the link, not the sort of style I am after but some useful ideas.

Answer (score 7):

You may have a look at the [qgis style hub](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/?is_gallery=true), here you will find several style that seem to fit your need.

If none of them seem right out of the box you can modify them or at last look at how the different effect are done and take hint from that to create your own (if you create some good one don't hesitate to share them in the hub)

EDIT

To get some overshoot you may use the `extend` function, the following example will draw polygon with overshoots varying at random between 0.1 and 1 unit at end and start (adjust the value to your need) :

```
extend(segments_to_lines( $geometry), randf(0.1 , 1),randf(0.1 , 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't find any that change the geometry with overshoots for example

Comment: I seem to remember a pencil style with overshoot but I cant find it again there.... See my edit for possible solution